# i want to show this type calender in android studio,

Tags: android, android-studio, calendar

[see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUGOS.jpg)

How will i do that?

Comment: See this I think this will behelp you. Reference Link : https://medium.com/@avi_kr16/creating-a-simple-android-calendar-in-7-steps-fa18a7945350

Comment: this is called horizontal calendar view, you can find it here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/horizontal-calendarview-in-android/